# Jdoodle online compiler terminal

Tags: c++, jdoodle

Whenever I enter a user input, the terminal enters the user input with every key pressed on the keyboard such as space,backspace,shift,etc

Here is the output from the terminal:

Enter full name.
John Bakersville
JShiftohn BShiftakersville

Sorry for the inconvenience, just confused.

Haven't really tried much. I've searched online but I don't know the issue. Thought it was the library but I don't know.

Comment: Peculiar. I don't think there's anything to do here except emailing owners of the website asking them to fix that "feature" and/or using a different tool to compile and run your code.

Comment: Thanks for your insight, I thought it was a simple issue with the lines of code but if it is the website then there's no helping it. I'll try to set up vs code.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend vscode to beginner. It's notoriously difficult to setup if you don't know what you are doing.